# Twisted Send Data to all Clients from Outside the Factory sessions with task Looping Call

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted

I'm trying to solve a simple Twisted problem.

I'm using the Python 2.7 Twisted Chat.py example for simplicity.

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
from twisted.internet import reactor

class Chat(LineReceiver):

    def __init__(self, users):
        self.users = users
        self.name = None
        self.state = "GETNAME"

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.sendLine("What's your name?")

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        if self.users.has_key(self.name):
            del self.users[self.name]

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        if self.state == "GETNAME":
            self.handle_GETNAME(line)
        else:
            self.handle_CHAT(line)

    def handle_GETNAME(self, name):
        if self.users.has_key(name):
            self.sendLine("Name taken, please choose another.")
            return
        self.sendLine("Welcome, %s!" % (name,))
        self.name = name
        self.users[name] = self
        self.state = "CHAT"

    def handle_CHAT(self, message):
        message = "<%s> %s" % (self.name, message)
        for name, protocol in self.users.iteritems():
            if protocol != self:
                protocol.sendLine(message)


class ChatFactory(Factory):

    def __init__(self):
        self.users = {} # maps user names to Chat instances

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Chat(self.users)


reactor.listenTCP(8123, ChatFactory())
reactor.run()
```

What I'm trying to do is use twisted.internet task to create a Task that runs every 60 seconds and sends data to all connected sessions.

semi Pseudocode

```
def broadcastmsg():
    for client in factory:
        client.protocol.transport.write("I am a Test\n\r")

event = task.LoopingCall(broadcastmsg)
event.start(60)
```

The issue is I can't get Twisted to behave correctly.   I can make it happen on a per session basis. But then for every use that connects it spams twice as much etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how are you setting up looping call?

As you know protocols are created and managed by factories. Sending some message to all users periodically looks like a task that should be put into factory. You can create loopingCall in factory `__init__` method and start it immediately after init. Since you have one factory per all connections this should send notifications only once per 60 seconds

```
class ChatFactory(Factory):

    def __init__(self):
        self.users = {} # maps user names to Chat instances

        def broadcast_msg():
            for name in self.users:
                self.users[name].sendLine("looping call send to users: {}".format(self.users.keys()))

        self.looping_call = task.LoopingCall(broadcast_msg)
        self.looping_call.start(60)
```

this should work ok, at least it does for me.

Comment: I did that but if I raise "error" in broadcast_msg the trace does not appear, even if I add the code ```d = self.looping_call.start(60); d.addErrback(twisted.python.log.err)``` Can you help with that?